# how to insert new row by using executeUpdate - FMdatabase

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using `fmdb` library.

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

I would like to insert new records but I don't know how can I do:

```
if let db = database, let q = db.executeUpdate("insert into \(table) (catid,subcat_id,id,subcat_title,title,description,lat,lon,takhfif,images,wifi,apple_health,wc,full_time,pos,work_hours,phone,mobile,fax,website,email,address,facebook,instagram,linkedin,telegram,googleplus,twitter,publish,feature,manager,city,rating_sum,rate_count,lastip,parking,isMallID,mallID,discount_images,price_images,newProduct_images,services_images,order_online,out_upon,cat_title,cat_icon,last_modify,item_logo,cat_logo,rate_sum1,rate_sum2,rate_sum3,rate_count1,rate_count2,rate_count3,rate_title1,rate_title2,rate_title3,rate_enable) values (\(catid),\(subcat_id),\(id),'\(subcat_title)','\(title)','\(description)','\(lat)','\(lon)','\(takhfif)','\(images)',\(wifi),\(apple_health),\(wc),\(full_time),\(pos),'\(work_hours)','\(phone)','\(mobile)','\(fax)','\(website)','\(email)','\(address)','\(facebook)','\(instagram)','\(linkedin)','\(telegram)','\(googleplus)','\(twitter)',\(publish),\(feature),'\(manager)','\(city)',\(rating_sum),\(rate_count),'\(lastip)',\(parking),\(isMallID),\(mallID),'\(discount_images)','\(price_images)','\(newProduct_images)','\(services_images)',\(order_online),\(out_upon),'\(cat_title)','\(cat_icon)',\(last_modify),'\(item_logo)','\(cat_logo)',\(rate_sum1),\(rate_sum2),\(rate_sum3),\(rate_count1),\(rate_count2),\(rate_count3),'\(rate_title1)','\(rate_title2)','\(rate_title3)',\(rate_enable))") {



        }
```

but I got this message before building:

> cannot invoke executeUpdate with an argument list of type string

[image]

Comment: Provide the code where you are getting the error, don't use screenshots, write it instead it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the api wrong. The first parameter is the sql, each value has to be represented with an "?". The second one (values) is an array of the values. Try this:

```
if let db = database, let q = db.executeUpdate(
    "insert into \(table) (catid,subcat_id,id,subcat_title,title,description,lat,lon,takhfif,images,wifi,apple_health,wc,full_time,pos,work_hours,phone,mobile,fax,website,email,address,facebook,instagram,linkedin,telegram,googleplus,twitter,publish,feature,manager,city,rating_sum,rate_count,lastip,parking,isMallID,mallID,discount_images,price_images,newProduct_images,services_images,order_online,out_upon,cat_title,cat_icon,last_modify,item_logo,cat_logo,rate_sum1,rate_sum2,rate_sum3,rate_count1,rate_count2,rate_count3,rate_title1,rate_title2,rate_title3,rate_enable) values (?, ?, ? ...., ?, ?, ? )"
    values: [catid, subcat_id, id, subcat_title, title, description, lat, lon, takhfif, images, wifi, apple_health, wc, full_time, pos, work_hours, phone, mobile, fax, website, email, address, facebook, instagram, linkedin, telegram, googleplus, twitter, publish, feature, manager, city, rating_sum, rate_count, lastip, parking, isMallID, mallID, discount_images, price_images, newProduct_images, services_images, order_online, out_upon, cat_title, cat_icon, last_modify, item_logo, cat_logo, rate_sum1, rate_sum2, rate_sum3, rate_count1, rate_count2, rate_count3, rate_title1, rate_title2, rate_title3, rate_enable]) {

}
```

Note: I didn't count the values, so you have to ensure that the count of "?" inside of the string is exactly the count of your values!

Maybe you should think about a function to improve the readability of your code. Something like that:

```
extension FMDatabase {

    func insert(into table: String, row values: [(column: String, content: Any)]) {
        guard (values.count > 0) else { fatalError(values.count > 0, "Inserting nothing into a table makes no sense!") }
        var sql = "INSERT INTO \(table) ("
        var contents: [Any] = []
        for (index, value) in values.enumerated() {
            sql += index == 0 ? value.column : ", \(value.column)"
            contents.append(value.content)
        }
        sql += ") VALUES ("
        for index in 0..<values.count {
            sql += index == 0 ? "?" : ", ?"
        }
        sql += ")"
        executeUpdate(sql, values: contents)
    }

}
```

Then you can insert values like that:

```
if let db = database {
    db.insert(
        into: table,
        row: [
            (column: "catid", content: catid),
            (column: "subcat_id", content: subcat_id),
            ...
            (column: "rate_enable", content: rate_enable)
        ]
    )
}
```

Isn't it better readable?